# Behavior of scala fold in parallel collections

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

Let's run the following line of code several times:

```
Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).par.fold(0)(_ - _)
```

The results are quite interesting:

```
scala> Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).par.fold(0)(_ - _)
res10: Int = 8
scala> Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).par.fold(0)(_ - _)
res11: Int = 20
```

However clearly it should be like in its sequential version:

```
scala> Set(1,2,3,4,5,6,7).fold(0)(_ - _)
res15: Int = -28
```

I understand that operation `-` is non-associative on integers and that's the reason behind such behavior, but my question is quite simple: doesn't it mean that `fold` should not be parallelized in `.par` implementation of collections?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you look at the [standard library documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce@fold[A1%3E:A](z:A1)(op:(A1,A1)=%3EA1):A1), you see that `fold` is undeterministic here:

> Folds the elements of this sequence using the specified associative binary operator.
>   The order in which operations are performed on elements is unspecified and may be nondeterministic.

As an alternative, there's `foldLeft`:

> Applies a binary operator to a start value and all elements of this sequence, going left to right.
>   Applies a binary operator to a start value and all elements of this collection or iterator, going left to right.
>
> Note: might return different results for different runs, unless the underlying collection type is ordered or the operator is associative and commutative.

As `Set` is not an ordered collection, there's no canonical order in which the elements could be folded, so the standard library allows itself to be undeterministic even for `foldLeft`. If you would use an ordered sequence here, `foldLeft` would be deterministic in that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Postponed doc reading as usual and was acting based on intuition :)

Comment: The scaladoc is a lie. `SeqLike#fold` actually uses `foldLeft`: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/1706a37eb84ec252aea77bccebad3e48448534ad/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L212

Comment: But it does not mean it is the same for par. They are actually implemented independently in parallel collections.

Comment: That's not a lie because `SeqLike` is a trait and this is only the default implementation that can be overwritten later (because it's not `final`)

Comment: It isn't the same for parallel collections. I'm pointing out that it _is_ the same for non-parallel collections that extend `TraversableOnce` (pretty much everything).

Comment: `SeqLike` inherits `fold` directly from `TraversableOnce`, so yes, it is a scaladoc copy failure in that case. There are many scaladoc errors like this throughout the standard library.

Comment: hm, you're right; haven't read enough api etheir. also, `ParSeq` and `Seq` have no dependency, so my api reference is also wrong

Comment: the difference between deterministic/nondeterministic should still be valid for ordered ParSeq's though

Comment: hm, I don't think there's a _copy_ failure in the scaladoc, it's just staying the same as the `SeqLike` trait extends `TraversableOnce`. And this also explicitly allows custom implementations to overwrite the default behaviour and do something more efficient

Comment: will check the scala book today about this

Answer (score 4):

The [scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParSet@fold%5BU%3E:T%5D(z:U)(op:(U,U)=%3EU):U) *does* say:

> The order in which the elements are reduced is unspecified and may be nondeterministic.

So, as you stated, a binary operation applied in `ParSet#fold` that is not associative is not guaranteed to produce a deterministic result. The above text is warning is all you get.

Does that mean `ParSet#fold` (and cousins) should not be parallelized? Not exactly. If your binary operation is commutative and you don't care about non-determinism of side-effects (not that a `fold` *should* have any), then there isn't a problem. However, you are hit with the caveat of needing to tread carefully around parallel collections.

Whether or not it is *correct* is more of a matter of opinion. One could argue that if a method can result in accidental non-determinism, that it should not exist in a language or library. But the alternative is to clip out functionality so that `ParSet` is missing functionality that is present in most of the other collection implementations. You *could* use the same line of thinking to also suggest the removal of `Stream#foreach` to prevent people from accidentally triggering infinite loops on infinite streams, but should you?

Comment: So we are talking about balance between reading documentation and having deterministic methods. Well, still debatable, but example with the Stream is nice. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to parallelize `fold` operation with high workloads, however, to guarantee a deterministic output from calling of `collection.par.fold(z)(f)`, the following conditions must hold: 
1- `f(f(a,b),c) == f(a,f(b,c))   // Associativity` 
2- `f(z,a) == f(a,z) == a` , where `z` is the neutral element for `f` (like 0 for sum, and 1 for multiplication).

Fabian's answer suggests using `foldLeft` instead. Although this is deterministic, using `.par` with it won't really parallelize anything. because `foldLeft` is sequential by nature.