# Functional way to mutate state inside higher order functions scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Consider the following code,

```
 1 var ip = ArrayBuffer[String]()
 2 ip += "1"
 3 println(ip)
 4 ip.clear()
 5 (1 to 10).foreach(ip += ("1"))
 6 println(ip)
```

Here in line no: 5 using variable `ip` inside higher order function results in exception. I do know using `var` is not advisable but I want to know how to use vars inside higher order functions. Or is there an alternative to mange state.

Comment: If you want to go the mutable route, just use a for loop: `for (_ <- 1 to 10) ip += "1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works:

```
(1 to 10).foreach(_ => ip += "1")
```

foldLeft is more functional and you can dispense with mutable state:

```
(1 to 10).foldLeft(List.empty[String]){
  case (acc, _) => "1" :: acc
}
```

Output:

```
List[String] = List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734007/behavior-of-scala-fold-in-parallel-collections